# XGboost installation error in Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pip, xgboost

Am trying to install Xgboost on my Mac. Python version is 3.6

```
sudo pip install xgboost
```

am getting the following error

```
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    rm -f -rf build build_plugin lib bin *~ /~ //*~ ///~ /.o //*.o ///.o xgboost
    clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
    /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
    make: * [build/learner.o] Error 127
    make:  Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
    /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
    make:  [build/logging.o] Error 127
    -----------------------------
    Building multi-thread xgboost failed
    Start to build single-thread xgboost
    rm -f -rf build build_plugin lib bin *~ /~ //*~ ///~ /.o //*.o ///.o xgboost
    clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
    /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
    make:  [build/learner.o] Error 127
    make:  Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
    /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
    make: * [build/logging.o] Error 127
    Successfully build single-thread xgboost
    If you want multi-threaded version
    See additional instructions in doc/build.md
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-TCLoWG/xgboost/setup.py", line 29, in 
        LIB_PATH = libpath'find_lib_path'
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-TCLoWG/xgboost/xgboost/libpath.py", line 45, in find_lib_path
        'List of candidates:\n' + ('\n'.join(dll_path)))
    builtin.XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Libarary in the candicate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?
    List of candidates:
    /private/tmp/pip-build-TCLoWG/xgboost/xgboost/libxgboost.so
    /private/tmp/pip-build-TCLoWG/xgboost/xgboost/../../lib/libxgboost.so
    /private/tmp/pip-build-TCLoWG/xgboost/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so
```

This is what happening, I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
$ brew install gcc@5
$ pip install xgboost
```

Info here https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1501

Answer (score 1):

Although I installed gcc 5 (with brew), the xgboost build still used the LLVM version of gcc (7 in my case). To get the build to use gcc 5 I did:

```
$ brew install gcc5
$ env CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 pip install xgboost
```

and this worked for me.
([davidread's answer](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1501) helps me very much! thank you @davidread)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem while installing by pip but installed successfully by this [link.](https://www.msmariquita.com/content/installing-xgboost-06-mac-os-x)

Comment: Thanks Devraj. Please provide some more context to the answer in case link gets broken in the future. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7658/289042